# How to run a SASS function from with in a string

Tags: css, sass

I have a sass include that has a sass function inside that needs to be run before compilation. For example I have this include

```
@include vendor-prefix("transform", "translate3d(0, reduceByHalf(-944px), 0)");
```

The result is

```
transform: translate3d(0, reduceByHalf(-944px), 0);
```

The reducebyHalf is not processed since it sits in the string. Here is what the reduceByHalf function looks like.

```
@function reduceByHalf($pxWidth, $negative:false) {

  @if $negative {
    @return -($pxWidth / 2);
  }

  @return $pxWidth / 2;
}
```

How can I run the reduceByHalf from within the string to produce the correct value?

As always any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: How does your vendor-prefix function look?
Does this help?  
`@include vendor-prefix("transform", unquote("translate3d(0, reduceByHalf(-994px), 0"))`

Comment: using unquote will simple remove the quotes, but won't invoke the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@include vendor-prefix("transform", "translate3d(0, #{reduceByHalf(-944px)}, 0)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around your value:

```
.foo {
    @include transform(translate3d(0, reduceByHalf(-944px), 0));
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -472px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -472px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, -472px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -472px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -472px, 0);
}
```